# Hide Keyboard in a view that loads a differnt view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am not able to hide the keyboard in my app.
My app  has 2 view.., The first view loads the another view. But when I do resignFirstResponder.., nothing is working...

Comment: can you post some related code...

Comment: please give some more detail with code

Comment: I have a UITextField inside a custom cell of a UITableView.., which is present in View2.., I am loading the view2 in view1 and trying to hide the keyboard upon hitting enter or.., when the touchesEnd..

Comment: I found out a solution to hide the keyboard,..., Since the tableViews has bounce event.., I implemeted the [self.textField endEditing:YES] in the scrollViewDidBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; method

Answer (score 1):

are you calling resignFirstResponder on a text component, like a UITextField or UITextView? Calling it on the containing view won't work.

Comment: Exactly !! I am calling the resignFirstResponder on UITextField ..., 
Is there any alernative for to achieve this ?

Comment: would

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

        [foo resignFirstResponder];


    }

work?

Comment: Yes it should. I would post some more of the surrounding code so we can see any potential issues. Just update the question with some code...

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies.. I found out a solution to hide the keyboard,..., Since the tableViews has bounce event.., I implemeted the [self.textField endEditing:YES] in the scrollViewDidBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; method.